# How do i set image.png that display white background, to blend with background image of webpage

Tags: css

[[image: this is the button that i am trying to remove the whitebackground from]]

```
<button id="closenav" cursor="pointer"><img id="closenavimg" src='images/left-arrow.png'></button>
```

```
#closenav{
    left: 25px;
    top:20px;
    position: relative;
    width:15px; 
    height: 15px;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 1;
}

#closenav #closenavimg{
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
    transition: transform 0.35s ease-out;
}
```

i tried changing the background attribute of my button to "background:url(image.png)" but it dosent display the png, so now im trying to se the background img of the button by placing an image inside the button element to display the image.

Answer (score 0):

never mind i was able to make it change by adding the following code in #closenav

```
background:url('images/left-arrow.png');
```